# PHP BCC Email not working

Tags: php

Continue from my last question about [PHP Sent Email Contains HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22599961/php-send-email-contains-html), Please help to advice, maybe I got wrong in my code :

```
$from = "Someone <someone@example.com>";
$to = "Someone 1 <someone1@example.com>";
$subject = "Test Send Email";
$body = "<div>Test</div>";
$emaillist = "sample@example.com";

$host = "mail.example.com";
$username = "someone";
$password = "blabla";

$headers = array(
'From'          => $from,
'To'            => $to,
'Subject'       => $subject,
'Content-Type'  => 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
'Bcc'           => $emaillist
);

$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
array ('host' => $host,
'auth' => true,
'username' => $username,
'password' => $password));

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

if (PEAR::isError($mail))
{
    echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
}
else
{
    echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
}
```

Running well, but when Bcc can't function. I see in another email listed Bcc, there is not receive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$bcc = "foo@example.com";
$to = "bar@example.com";
$headers = array(..other stuff.., 'To' => $to, ..rest of header stuff); // No Bcc header!
$recipients = $to.", ".$bcc;
$mail = $smtp->send($recipients, $headers, $message);
```

Reference: [Sending multiple CC's and BCCs with PHP PEAR MAIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311429/sending-multiple-ccs-and-bccs-with-php-pear-mail)

Answer (score 0):

try to set Bcc like this

```
$headers['Bcc'] = 'cc@example.com, bb@example.com, dd@ex.com';
```